# Outlook large folder list, any way to show new mail in folders at the top?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I use outlook daily, communication between businesses, customers, internal departments and so on.
This results in an excessive folder list, each having rules so emails go into their designated folder.

The issue I have is I miss new emails coming in from folders at the bottom of my list. Basically the first 20 folders show perfect in the Pane, however on busy days I simply don't scroll down the folder list and therefore may miss emails until the next day when I have more free time to go up and down all my emails.

Is there any shortcut or custom Pane where folders can display at the top that have New / Unread emails?

Has anyone else had such problems? Or do people just spend more time in outlook going through all their folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution might be to create a Search Folder that contains all the
unread emails.

- In the Home pane, New group, click New Search Folder
- In the dialog, select Reading Mail > Unread mail
- Select your email address at the bottom
- Click OK
- To make the Unread Mail folder more visible, drag it under Favorites.

Note that deleting a message in the Search Folder, will also delete it
from its folder.

Comment: This is perfect thank you, Never knew this existed!! Exactly what am after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a solution for a custom pane etc, but I found out that it's possible to tick the option to "display in the New Item Alert window" when creating a rule: [image: see the image.]

Adding this option to every rule you have could be the solution for your problem. I recommend testing it out before adding to every single rule though.

Comment: Yes thanks for this, i had tried this option, however enabling this stops the Rule from working on the 365 and is specific to outlook only. Meaning any time i check the emails on my phone, the rules wont operate.